# AppRTC storing the audio locally

Tags: ios, iphone, webrtc, audio-recording, apprtc

I am using AppRTC which is a iOS wrapper of WebRTC,
I need to record the audio of the Video Call, so that we can play the audio later if needed.

I tried using `AVAudioRecorder`, but it only records the input of microphone (not the external speakers).

How to record the conversation to a audio file?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: no luck, let me know if you find any solution.